# Get values from JSON with Powershell

Tags: json, powershell

Very beginner question. I'm trying to get certain values from JSON with Powershell.. Specifically, I want to list the Services: **TEST00000** and **FAKE** only.

When I run the script below, I get this:

```
TEST00000                                                    FAKE           
---------                                                    ----           
@{Enabled=True; Processed=2; Sent=3; Failed=4; Downloaded=5} @{Enabled=True}
```

How can I get a list of only the services?

More importantly, how do I list only the services which has the key/value *Enabled=True* present inside of them?

Here is the code:

```
$JSON = '{
  "Envs": {
    "DEV": {
      "Services": {
        "TEST00000": {
          "Enabled": true,
          "Processed": 2,
          "Sent": 3,
          "Failed": 4,
          "Downloaded": 5
        },
        "FAKE": {
          "Enabled": true
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "Component": {
    "Digger": {
      "Envs": {
        "DEV": {
          "DownloadE": 4
        }
      }
    }
  }
}'

$jsonobj = ConvertFrom-Json -inputObject $JSON

$jsonobj.Envs.DEV.Services
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get the name of each `Services` property. You can use `Get-Member` like user2734259 did or you can use the `psobject` property which stores useful information about an object.

```
$ServiceNames = $jsonobj.Envs.DEV.Services.psobject.properties.name
```

Once you have the names you can loop over them and filter on the sub-property `Enabled`

```
$jsonobj.Envs.DEV.Services.psobject.properties.name | ForEach-Object { 
    $_ | Where-Object {$jsonobj.Envs.DEV.Services.$_.Enabled -eq $True}
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply, this was super interesting, I spent a lot of time trying to look for this info, how did you guys learn this? Where can I do further reading about this? (or is it learning the art of using the PS help content!?)

Comment: @ToastMan I personally started with the Don Jones Month of Lunches books. Knowing about the hidden `psobject` property I picked up on from someone's answer on SO (been too long to remember who).

Comment: Hm the last part doesn't seem to work: $_ | Where-Object {$jsonobj.Envs.DEV.Services.$_.Enabled -eq 'false'} <-- lists the services anyways (with the -eq 'false')

Comment: @ToastMan Updated my answer to fix the issue. This was because the `Enabled` property is a boolean. And when you try to cast the string `'false'` to a boolean, it turns into `$True`. You can test this with `[bool]'false'`.

Answer (score 1):

This should allow you to get the names dynamically, regardless of the service name in your JSON:

```
$JSON = '{
  "Envs": {
    "DEV": {
      "Services": {
        "TEST00000": {
          "Enabled": true,
          "Processed": 2,
          "Sent": 3,
          "Failed": 4,
          "Downloaded": 5
        },
        "FAKE": {
          "Enabled": true
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "Component": {
    "Digger": {
      "Envs": {
        "DEV": {
          "DownloadE": 4
        }
      }
    }
  }
}'

$jsonobj = ConvertFrom-Json -inputObject $JSON
$enabledServices = $NULL
$disabledServices = $NULL

# Since the service names are arbitrary
# create an object that contains only
# objects whose MemberType is NoteProperty

$strServiceNames = @($($jsonobj.Envs.DEV.Services | Get-Member | Where { $_.MemberType -eq "NoteProperty" } | Select Name).Name)
$pscoServiceNames = [PSCustomObject]@{Names=$strServiceNames}
foreach($serviceName in $pscoserviceNames.Names)
{
    # dynamically access the service name
    # from $jsonobj.Envs.DEV.Services

    $serviceStatus = $jsonobj.Envs.DEV.Services.$serviceName.Enabled

    # parse results based on value of .Enabled

    if($serviceStatus.ToString() -eq "True")
    {
        $enabledServices = [Array]$enabledServices + [PSCustomObject]@{Name = $serviceName;Enabled = $serviceStatus}
    }
    else
    {
        $disabledServices = [Array]$disabledServices + [PSCustomObject]@{Name = $serviceName;Enabled = $serviceStatus}
    }
}

# Show the results

Write-Output "`nEnabled Services`n"
$enabledServices | Format-List
Write-Output "`nDisabled Services`n"
$disabledServices | Format-List
```

If anything is unclear let me know and I can explain in more detail
Hope this helps you out.
Happy 'shelling!

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply, this was super interesting !

Comment: if($serviceStatus -eq "False") <-- gives me the exact same results: 
Enabled Services

Name    : FAKE
Enabled : True

Name    : TEST00000
Enabled : True

Comment: @toastman  I will revisit when I'm back at the machine where I wrote the code and fix if necessary and edit my answer for the sake of completeness. Think it might be a type problem but will check. Til then, happy holidays

Comment: Yep, it was a type error. $serviceStatus is boolean so it needed to be converted to a string to match the regex.

So just change that one line to:

`if($serviceStatus.ToString() -eq "False")` and it should work as needed

Comment: Many thanks trebleCode. I ended up marking BenH response as the solution as I used his code at the end. But I highly appreciate your help.

Comment: No worries, happy to help anytime