# Powershell - Get array of non-null values from fields in multiple rows of a PSObject (or multiple JSON array items)?

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0

I have some JSON like this (which came from a PSObject):

```
[
    {
        "cf_workflow_1":  1212,
        "cf_workflow_2":  null,
        "cf_workflow_3":  null
    },
    {
        "cf_workflow_1":  null,
        "cf_workflow_2":  9797,
        "cf_workflow_3":  null
    },
    {
        "cf_workflow_1":  6262,
        "cf_workflow_2":  null,
        "cf_workflow_3":  null
    }
]
```

I want to pull out an array that is simply:

```
(1212,9797,6262)
```

How would I go about doing that?

Here is some sample code to work with:

```
$tickets = @"
        [
            {
                "cf_workflow_1":  1212,
                "cf_workflow_2":  null,
                "cf_workflow_3":  null
            },
            {
                "cf_workflow_1":  null,
                "cf_workflow_2":  9797,
                "cf_workflow_3":  null
            },
            {
                "cf_workflow_1":  6262,
                "cf_workflow_2":  null,
                "cf_workflow_3":  null
            }
        ]
"@

$ticketsObject = $tickets | ConvertFrom-Json 

#Show the ticket data
$ticketsObject | Format-Table -AutoSize

#Create an array to hold all the non-null workflow numbers
#It should eventually contain the value (1212,9797,6262)
$workflowNumbers = @()

#Not sure what to do here to return only the non-null workflow numbers as an array?
$workflowNumbers = $ticketsObject | foreach{$_}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [get-values-from-json-with-powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47944727/get-values-from-json-with-powershell)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works:

```
$ticketsObject | 
  ForEach-Object {$_.Psobject.properties | 
                 where-Object {$_.Name -like 'cf*' -and $_.Value } | select -expand Value}
```

The idea was to look at the properties of each object (only the cf* ones) and only the ones that had a value, and then just get the Values.